# Let the EventHandler wait for a function

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, async-await, eventhandler

I have got the following problem.

I have two ObservableCollections `coll1`, `coll2`. When adding to the first ObservableCollection `coll1` I add in the `coll1_CollectionChanged` some manipulated data into the `coll2` - this fires up the `coll2_CollectionChanged`.

According to the Action (Add, Remove, Reset) i let the `coll2_CollectionCHanged` call a function. The issue is, that this function (let me call it `func1`) starts another asynchronous function(a query). After the query call, the function `func1` should do another actions - updating some data.

The problem is, that the `coll2_CollectionChanged` EventHandler should wait until the `func1` is ready (including the query), but it doesn't. All in all there are three Add Actions to the `coll2_CollectionCHanged` and after each Add the EventHandler should wait for the `func1` get ready.

The query in the `func1` is an asynchronous function. I marked the `func1` as async and call the query with await. Than I let the EventHandler call the `func1` also as async - I make the EventHandler async and call the `func1` with await. But it doesn't wait.

Comment: can you show how the code actually looks like?

Comment: I cannot show it now, cause the code is at work. but it looks like I described it)

Comment: Well then, what you described should work.

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't wait.

Sure it does. The event *handler* is paused, waiting for `func1` to complete. While it's paused, it returns to its caller - the central point of `async`.

The behavior you want is to have the code *raising* the `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` event to (asynchronously) wait for the event handler to complete. This is not easy; trying to twist the built-in `ObservableCollection` class to support this would be very difficult (maybe impossible).

A far easier solution is to change your logic so that, say, your *other* code will asynchronously wait for `func1` so that it knows all side effects have been applied.